# NOT and NAND Logic gate

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

My working

.Z passes though NAND becoming Z'

.Y passes through NOT gate becoming Y'

.Y' Passes though NAND becoming Y

therefore answer is Z'Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs to the NAND gate (1) are $Z$ and $\overline{Y}$. The image below shows a breakdown of a NAND gate in terms of an AND gate and a NOT gate.

[image]

In your case, let $A = Z, B = \overline Y$. The output of the NAND gate is then $\overline{\left(Z\overline Y\right)} = \overline Z  + Y$ and so the correct answer is option 3.